# Trigger paypal donate on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, paypal

i'm working on a paypal donate feature in a rails 4 app. I'm not very familiar with paypal api, so any advices about the right way to work with it are welcome.

**What i want to do:**

the donate page is a form to create a new Donateur object who will hold all informations about the donator like name, email, status of the donation (paid or not) etc

When a user fill and submit this form to make a donation, i want to redirect him to the paypal paiement page (after the form submission has succeed).

Then, when paypal donation is done, IPN send to my app the paiement datas so i can update the previous Donateur entry created and fill informations about the success or failure of the donation.

**What i got**

I have the classic form for creating a new Donateur object, nothing special here.

In my controller, i wonder how i can redirect user to the paiement page of my paypal account

```
#donateurs_controller.rb
def create
  @donateur = Donateur.new(post_params)
  @donateur.save ? redirect_to(PAYPAL_DONATE_PAGE) : render('index')
end
```

The callback (after paiement) doesn't matter for the moment

**My question**

Donations with paypal are they classic transactions (so i could use the api like if i was selling some products) or should i specifiy something about it s a donation while make a payement call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've fix my problems. I used this gem https://github.com/paypal/buttonmanager-sdk-ruby to generate a donate button on form submit. I can get programmaticaly the api request url sent when clicking this button, so i don't have to display it on the screen.